# Is it possible to extract coefficients from MARS model without hinge functions?

Tags: nonlinear-regression, mars

I have a MARS model, say:

```
set.seed(1111)

test <- tibble(
  x1 = runif(rnorm(5000, 5, 10)) * .33, 
  x2 = runif(rnorm(5000, 5, 10)) * .44,
  x3 = runif(rnorm(5000, 5, 10)) * .55,
  x4 = runif(rnorm(5000, 5, 10)) * .66,
  y = runif(rnorm(5000, 10, 2)) * 10
)

test_fit <- earth(y ~ ., data = test)

test_fit |> 
  coef() |> 
  broom::tidy()
```

And as it is expected I recieve coefficients for my predictors with hinge functions. But I wonder whether it is possible to get the coefficient value for the predictor without any hinge function? I want to present a formula with raw coefficients like, so the non-technical audience will understand:

```
Y = coefficient1 * X1 + coefficient2 + X2 + ...
```

Comment: And how would you do that? You have to specify somewhere that this coefficients only work in some subspaces.

Comment: An option would be to roll out the hinges and write out all the formulas for all the splits with only the non-zero variables, which may result in a lot of formulas.